# Define Color and Transparency by expression

Tags: qgis, symbology, expression

I am trying to define the coloring and transparency for the overview in the Atlas by an expression.
If the value of a field is equal zero, I don't want any overview, so transparency would be zero. If the value of a field is greater than zero, then I want a transparency of 50% or whatever.

I have tried with IF and CASE
IF("Nr." = 0, '255,0,0,0', '255,0,0,50')

but it never differentiates. The transparency does not change upon the value of the field, it remains the same.

Is there a possibility to only set the transparency/opacity by expression?

[image: A screenshot of my problem]

The overview map is fully red, although in this case the "Nr." = 0 case should apply and take the red overlay away fully, i.e. 100% transparency.

Comment: 1) what is your field type? 2) Is it 0 or NULL?

Comment: Field type is Integer and value is actual "0". NULL value also exists, but that would go together with "!=0". If =0 -> no overview (100% transparency), if >0 or NULL (!=0) -> 50% transparency.

Comment: I'd suggest using:  if( "Nr." > 0, '255,0,0,50', '255,0,0,0' ) that will handle nulls and 0s properly as the fallback.

Comment: I have tried that. For some reason it does work. When I use your code (same what I tried before) it switches to Opacity=0 for all cases, although in the expression preview it shows me the correct case depending on the feature. I am getting really frustrated :(

Comment: I found the issue, I'll spare you the technicalities, but instead of using the field directly replace it with attribute(  @atlas_feature  ,'Nr.')

Comment: I thought I had tried something like that also....obviously not in the right way. It worked!!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: The situation should be fixed in the upcoming releases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug, a ticket was created.

There is a discrepancy between the expression in the expression builder and during the actual evaluation. To work around this issue the attribute of the atlas feature must be fetched instead of directly using the field.

Until a proper fix, use this instead of "Nr." directly.

```
attribute( @atlas_feature ,'Nr.')
```

*UPDATE*

The situation in qgis should be fixed in the upcoming releases, thanks to Nyall.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand well, this is how I would do it :

In the layer property, tab "symbology"

You go to "Fill color", you edit the expression :

```
CASE WHEN "Field" = 0 THEN color_rgba(255,0,0, 0) ELSE color_rgba(255,0,0, 255) END
```

The 3 first number are the colors in RGB from 0 to 255, the last one is the alpha value (transparency), from 0 to 255.

You can also use expression on "Opacity" like this :

```
CASE WHEN "Field" = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 50 END
```

So if your layer has multiple symbols, stroke, etc. it's working on the whole symbology.

I hope I've been clear.

[image: Opacity]
[image: Color]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this does not solve my problem because it is regarding the overview map in the atlas generator. I want the red box that indicates the extent on an overview map to be fully transparent (=non-existent) when "Field" = 0 and for example 50% when "Field" > 0. I have added a screenshot to my initial post that maybe clarifies the problem better. It seems like a very straight forward and trivial issue but it doesn't work :/